# Pigeonhole Principle homework problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

How to solve this problem using Pigeonhole Principle?

> A worker plans to work 60 hours in the next 37 days, and he works at least 1 h/day, show that he will be working 13 hours in total in some continuous days.

So there are 23 hours more to spend on 37 days, but how is that related to 13 on continuous days?

Comment: And... what did you try?

Comment: @LazyLee So there are 23 hours more to spend on 37 days, but how is that related to 13 on continuous days?

Comment: @pwd why don't you break up your problem into blocks of $n$ continuous days where he works at least $n$ hours/block. Choose an appropriate $n$ and then apply PPP to the blocks. (Also, your question would have been much better imo had your comment been part of it).

Comment: @ZainPatel PPP... pigeon pole principle?

Comment: @ZainPatel ... I don't understand your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the total amount of the worker has worked from the first day until the $n-$th day by $S_n$.

Now $S_n\leq 60$ and $A_n=S_n+13 \leq 73$ for all $n$.

Both $S_n,A_n$ are between $1$ and $73$ and there are $74$ of them. Consequently, by the pigeonhole principle, there are two of them that are equal.

From your condition that the worker works at least one hour per day the collection of $S_n$ are pairwise distinct and the same holds for the $A_n$ family. Therefore there are $n_1$ and $n_2$ such that $A_{n_1}=S_{n_2}$ whence
$S_{n_2}-S_{n_1}=13$.

So we conclude that the desired time interval where the worker worked for exactly $13$ hours is between days $n_1+1, n_1+2, \cdots, n_2$

Comment: "total amount of TIME the worker has worked"

Comment: why by the pigeonhole principle there are 2 of them are equal?

Comment: @pwd We have  $74$ numbers $S_1, S_2, \cdots , S_{37}, A_1, A_2,\cdots, A_{37}$  and for all $i$ $1 \leq A_i\leq 73$ and $1 \leq S_i \leq 73$. So, we have 74 integers between $1$ and $73$ therefore two of these numbers much be the same. The numbers are the pigeons and the value each number corresponds to is the hole.

Comment: @clark could you suggest a textbook where similar problems and/or this kind of reasoning is used/taught

Comment: OK, I get it, I think it should be $1\leq S_i \leq 60$ and $14\leq A_i \leq 73$ to be more precise though.

Comment: @magma One book you could try is Problem-Solving methods in Combinatorics an Olympian approach, by Pablo Soberon it has a nice collection of problems with solutions. However, you could also try asking a question saying exactly what you are looking for, your goals your level to get perhaps a suggestion more tailored to your needs by someone more knowledgeable than me.

Comment: @clark thanks, I will check it out